# Which JVM implementation can do sharing of Java Objects off-heap or across multiple processes?

Tags: java, jvm

According to https://patents.google.com/patent/US6842759 this seems possible with the JVM.

My question would be, which JVM implementation (*IBM*, *Oracle*, or something else) can do sharing of Java Objects off-heap or across multiple processes?

EDIT:

I am not referring to interprocess communication (IPC) nor caching (e.g. using EHCache or ChronicleMap, etc.), like sharing serialized data structures but, I mean instances of Java classes from one process to another.

Comment: According here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761177/is-terracotta-a-distributed-cache Terracotta might solve this requirement making multiple JVM behave as one

Comment: Does this including threads?

Comment: @NomadMaker yes I think so, http://www.uwyn.com/download/intro_terracotta.pdf